# Perhaps a function pointer or casting problem. Not sure

Tags: c, string

What's happening in this code?
I don't get this code. Looks like it's performing some type of casting or using function pointers but I'm not sure. Will appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks.

```
const char string[]="Hello!";

int main()   
{

    (*(void (*)()) string)(); //Obviously, my problem is this line :)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are casting string to a function, and calling it.  This almost certainly segfaults

Comment: This was basically a program to test a shellcode, but I changed it (read: removed the shellcode).

Does not segfaults on Opensuse 11.2 when I use the actual shellcode instead of "Hello!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) to explain the inner gibberish:

```
$ cdecl
cdecl> explain (void (*)())
cast unknown_name into pointer to function returning void
```

So `(void (*)()) string` casts `string` into a function pointer. Then the function pointer is dereferenced to call the underlying function. The line is equivalent to

```
void (*fp)() = (*(void (*)()) string)();
(*fp)();
```

This (on most machines) tries to execute "Hello!" as machine code. It may crash outright on machines with virtual memory because data is often marked as non-executable. If it doesn't crash, it's not likely to do anything coherent. In any case, this is not useful code.

The only thing to learn here is that the `cdecl` tool can be useful to understand or write complicated C types and declarations.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to cdecl.org! What a fantastic little service!

Comment: Thanks! It really helped me.
Also, thanks for introducing me too to cdecl.

Answer (score 3):

`void (*)()` is a function pointer type. `(void (*)()) string` casts `string` to such a function pointer. The remaining `(* ...)()` in the expression dereferences this resulting function pointer and tries to call the function.

Since there isn't any function where that pointer points to, but only the string "Hello!", this won't lead to any useful results.